# Upload 2 files from 2 inputs with Flask

Tags: html, forms, flask

I need to have 2 buttons for uploading 2 different files by using Flask, but I cannot find the way to do that.

The answer that I found several times was to add "multiple" in parameters, but this is not what I want because I need to have a button for each file.

In my form I need the onchange="form.submit() parameter, and I want to have others entries.

The files I have tu upload are excel files

upload.html :

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="input-field">
        <input type="text" name="other_input" onchange="form.submit()" id="other_input">
    <label>Other Input</label>
  </div>
  <div class="div_files">                             
    <label class="Button"> Select File 1</label>
       <input name="1st_file" type="file" onchange="form.submit()" value="1st_file">                                 
    <label class="Button"> Select File 2</label>
      <input name="2nd_file" type="file" onchange="form.submit()" value="2nd_file">                                                                             
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Show result" action="other" id="btns">                              
</form>
```

app.py :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index, methods=['POST', 'GET'])')
def index():
  file1 = request.files["1st_file"]
  file2 = request.files["2nd_file"]
  return render_template('other_page.html', variable1=file1, variable2=file2)
```

I tried to use 2 different forms to get what I want, but it didn't work either

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I recommend that you set the "POST" method and the "multipart/form-data" enctype in your form so that the files can be transferred.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to add them in the publication, but I set the method and the enctype also, and it doesn't work :/